# Bootstrap reduce space between text in button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;background-color:#eeeeee" disabled>
  <h5 style="color:#000000"><i><b>1,39€</b></i></h5>
  <small style="color:#000000" class="FuelName"><b>@fuel.Name</b></small>
</button>
```

[image]

But I want the distance between "1,39€" and "LNG" close,
how to archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use [**Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) *class* `m-0` on `h5` selector.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Bootstrap 5 / Inside Button spacing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="m-2 p-2">
<h6>before</h6>
<button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;background-color:#eeeeee" disabled>
  <h5 style="color:#000000"><i><b>1,39€</b></i></h5>
  <small style="color:#000000" class="FuelName"><b>LNG</b></small>
</button>

<h6>after</h6>
<button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;background-color:#eeeeee" disabled>
  <h5 style="color:#000000" class="m-0"><i><b>1,39€</b></i></h5>
  <small style="color:#000000"><b>LNG</b></small>
</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At `h5` element you should control margin-bottom, the heading elements in bootstrap have some default values.

Try something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;background-color:#eeeeee" disabled>
    <h5 style="color:#000000; margin-bottom:0"><i><b>1,39€</b></i></h5>
    <small style="color:#000000" class="FuelName"><b>@fuel.Name</b></small>
</button>
```